# Adapter as Presenter? Or talking with a Presenter? Android and MVP

Tags: android, mvp

I'm trying to follow the MVP pattern. However, I have some doubts on how to handle adapters and view holders on this pattern.

Should I use the adapter as a presenter? Having the business logic?

Or should I pass a instance of the presenter that handles the list logic and then call methods of the presenter when there is any interaction with the adapter elements?

Thank you

Comment: I think that Android view adapters are purely V-scope stuff, and if the adapters are presenters -- these presenters are internal somewhere in a view implementation. Also, presenters should not contain business logic as they are just mediators between M and V. In my current MVP-based project, presenters are not aware of list adapters at all as they should not care how a _list of something_ is displayed (e.g., a presenter justs tells a view: "display routes somehow", and just listens to a view event "onRouteSelected" as the route can be obtained from any kind of widgets, not necessarily a list).

Comment: So, do you have a reference to a presenter inside the adapter? Or do you add listeners to adapters events and then redirect to the presenter? @LyubomyrShaydariv

Comment: Yes, the second case: the adapters can interact with the hosting views, and then a particual view decides how to transform/delegate an event to a presenter (or a presenter listener -- depends on how you separate presenters and listeners interfaces).

Answer (score 4):

There is no exact/correct definition of implementing MVP in Android

To answer your question, in my view the `Presenter` should not have any Android logic.

As such, the `Adapter` would be a "`View`" then i.e. Presenter provides it the data (via the `Activity` or `Fragment`) and it just deals with how to present this.

I'd do MVP as follow.

1. **Model** - POJO's, parsing, Storing (SQLlite) and retrieving data (http). Obviously I'd divide the POJO's, parsing and DB logic into sub folders - but this all falls into Model for me.
2. **View** - `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Adapters` - Activities & Fragment hold reference to a Presenter that gives them data to display. How this data/messages are displayed, look + feel etc. is dealt with in the `View`.
3. **Presenter** - The Middle man, provides the logic to inputs i.e. Button Clicks, retrieval of data, validation of inputs & then passes the result back to the View (`Activity` or `Fragment`)

Here's a great article on [MVP](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/)

Here's a simplified [diagram](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/designpatterninandroid-140926020616-phpapp02/95/design-pattern-in-android-12-638.jpg?cb=1411697226) of MVP

[image]

Answer modified from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176007/mvp-design-for-android-how-to-adopt-to-my-application/41182969#41182969) (also answered by me)