# MVP Design for Android: How to adopt to my application?

Tags: android, mvp

I am writing an application that will have a `JSON` file which contains data that should be parsed and saved into `ItemModel` POJOs.

Let's assume for now I have a simple `Activity` that displays nothing at all - all I want my application to do is on startup parse the `JSON` and create the model objects (I'd like to figure out the basic architecture of these pieces before moving onto bigger/better things).  I'd like to unit test this code before making any UI components to ensure my model classes are working OK.

So, the `ItemModel` is obviously a model object.

Where does the `JSON` parsing fall in terms of MVP?  The library to parse the data (`Gson`, `Jackson`, or something else?) will surely require an Android `Context` to achieve this, so should I be parsing that information in the `Activity`? If yes, now the view knows about `Model` classes, which breaks MVP.

Also if I wanted to them persist the `ItemModel`/`JSON` data in a database, where would that be done? The database should technically be in the model - but again that requires a `Context` in order to work correctly...

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact/correct definition of implementing MVP in Android

Here's a great article on [MVP](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/)

I'd do MVP as follow.

1. **Model** - POJO's, parsing, Storing (SQLlite) and retrieving data (http). Obviously I'd divide the POJO's, parsing and DB logic into sub folders - but this all falls into Model for me.
2. **View** - `Activity`, `Fragment`, `Adapters` - Activities & Fragment hold reference to a Presenter that gives them data to display. How this data/messages are displayed, look + feel etc. is dealt with in the View.
3. **Presenter** - The Middle man, provides the logic to inputs i.e. Button Clicks, retrieval of data, validation of inputs & then passes the result back to the View (`Activity` or `Fragment`)

Here's a simplified [diagram](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/designpatterninandroid-140926020616-phpapp02/95/design-pattern-in-android-12-638.jpg?cb=1411697226) of MVP

[image]