# Android : best case for communicating adapter with Activity/Fragment

Tags: android, android-adapter, mvp, event-bus

In MVP pattern, action from user must deliver to presenter

so in listView when user click on item I want send this action to presenter

what is the best case for communicating adapter with Activity/Fragment?

and I appreciate it if you explain pros and cond of each one.

1. EventBus
2. CallBack

Comment: You can take a look at this sample project http://github.com/mmirhoseini/marvel and this article https://hackernoon.com/yet-another-mvp-article-part-1-lets-get-to-know-the-project-d3fd553b3e21 to get more familiar with MVP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your scenario u can adopt given below methods

```
Try using an interface
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16443645/4247543

```
if the above method is not helping then try using EventBus
```

please follow below link to know more of Event Bus

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

http://gunhansancar.com/ease-communication-between-activities-fragments-services/

```
BroadcastReceiver as mentioned could also help for enabling communication.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10084754/4247543

```
You can use observers
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964385/4247543

Hopes it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The communication between `View` & `Presenter` should be through an `interface`.

Both `Presenter` and `Activity` (view) have their own `interface`.

1. So a List item click item is forward to a Presenter.
2. The Presenter decides what to do. i.e. open a DetailsActicity
3. Call's the Activity to start new Intent.

Here's a good example of MVP [interfaces](http://hannesdorfmann.com/mosby/mvp/)

A good/brief explanation of [MVP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176007/mvp-design-for-android-how-to-adopt-to-my-application/41182969#41182969)

**Edit**

- Communication between `Adapter` & `Activity`/`Fragment`.

First point - in my personal view `Adapter` & `Activity`/`Fragment`are all subsections of `View` in the MVP architecture.

The `Activity` will hold reference to the `Adapter`

The `Activity` (via the `Presenter`) can mainpualte the data in the adapter by the usual means i.e. changing the underlying data object and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

As for the `Adapter` sending requests back to the `Activity` i.e. `View.OnClickListener` this can be done via callbacks that are sent when the `Adapter` is first initialised (i.e. created using the `new` keyword)

Comment: tnx for response, but my question is about communication between adapter with fragment, not presenter/view

Answer (score 0):

You can always use callbacks for listening clicks. You should implement is using interfaces.